# how do i select as options the external html file elements and show it in a div with jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I want to show the elements from an external html file called h12_load.html into a selection list and if one of them gets clicked it gets shown into the div called divResult.

the first option doesn't get added to the divResult when it is selected/clicked.

This is what i tried:

HTML & JQuery:

```
<select name="" id="SelectionList">
    <option value="" id="option1"></option>
    <option value="" id="option2"></option>
</select>
<div id="divResult"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        let option1 = $('#option1').append().load('h12_load.html #content')
        let option2 = $('#option2').append().load('h12_load.html #meerContent')
        $('#SelectionList').on('change', function () {
            if ($('#option1').is(':selected')) {
                $('#divResult').append(option1)
            } if ($('#option2').is(':selected')) {
                $('#divResult').append(option2)
            }

        }

        )
    })
</script>
```

External HTML file:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Deze inhoud wordt geladen via $.load()</h2>
</div>
<div id="meerContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit....</p>
</div>
```

Please help, thanks already!

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: the first option doesn't get added to the divResult when it is selected/clicked.

Comment: @David is this better?

Comment: When you debug, what specifically happens?  Do the `.load()` operations successfully update the DOM as expected?  When a selection is made, is the `change` handler invoked?  What specifically happens within that handler?  If the `.load()` operations successfully modify the DOM as expected, can you hard-code that into a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The load operations successfully updated the dom and the change handler is invoked when a selection is made. But the only thing now is that the options are shown in the select bar but when clicked they don't show in the div called divResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the first option doesn't get added to the divResult when it is selected/clicked.

But the second one does?  It sounds like you're just not able to *change* the option *to* the first one.  After all, the `<select>` only has two options.  One will be selected by default.  So selecting that one (the first one) doesn't *change* the selection.  If you select the second one, that element gets moved to the `<div>`, which leaves the `<select>` with *one* option, which is already selected.

So you've created a `<select>` where the first option is always already selected and can't be un/re-selected.

Add an empty option as the default:

```
<select name="" id="SelectionList">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="" id="option1"></option>
  <option value="" id="option2"></option>
</select>
```

Then you can select either of the other options.  And when you do so and that option gets moved to the `<div>`, the empty option will again be the default.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but after i click the options from the select menu, the options get dissapeared. How do i keep the options in the select menu through clicking and changing from option to option? i have to refresh the page to reselect one of the options now...

Comment: @user22934804: Because those elements are being *moved* to the `<div>`.  Did you mean to do something else instead?  Maybe [clone the element](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and append that clone to the `<div>`?

Comment: I tried to clone it but it doesn't work. it just appears in the options bar and not in the seperate div. I want to show the options in the options bar and at the same time getting added in the div when clicked on and showing in the div.

Comment: @user22934804: Using `.clone()` [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/j3h4w0dy/).  If you're having issues cloning the elements then that may be worth a new Stack Overflow question, specifically to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Its working, thanks for the answer, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you define two variables (option1 and option2), I think it would be better this way.

```
$('#SelectionList').on('change', function () {
    $('#divResult').empty();
    if ($('#option1').is(':selected')) {
        $('#divResult').load('h12_load.html #content')
    } if ($('#option2').is(':selected')) {
        $('#divResult').load('h12_load.html #meerContent')
    }
}
```

The method [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) itself append to the element, I also added `$('#divResult').empty();` to clean the div before adding another element again.

I didn't test this but try it out and let us know.

Comment: You also need to check if h12_load.html exists on the same folder, otherwise you would have to specify the correct path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesn't work unfortunately. There are no options available to click on.